# How to keep a page stay at the same position after the page reloads and after switching to another page using React hooks?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I am facing a problem with my app, every time when I am switching from one page to another and then get back to the preview the page t doesn't stay in the same position as when I left it, and also when I reload the page. Can have some advice on how to fix it? Below is what I try to achieve but it not working.

**Story.ts:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Story =()=>{
const elementRef = useRef(null);

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('element-id');
    const position = { x: element.scrollLeft, y: element.scrollTop };
    localStorage.setItem('mapPosition', JSON.stringify(position));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedPosition = localStorage.getItem('mapPosition');
    if (storedPosition !== null) {
      const position = JSON.parse(storedPosition);
      window.scrollTo(position.x, position.y);
    }
  }, []);

return(

<div id='element-id'>
<h1>Title here</h1>
<p>
some text here
</p>
</div>

)

}
```